# 64-bit DBeaver can't connect to ODBC source - "Parameter number out of range."

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, dbeaver, pervasive-sql

I have a program on a server running Pervasive SQL.  I can connect to it via an ODBC connection running the Pervasive ODBC connector.  In the Windows ODBC Manager(s) I can create sources and connect in both 32-bit and 64-bit. (Test Connection is successful).

In DBeaver 32-bit I can connect to this data source with no problem; but the latest version of DBeaver is 64-bit only. They no longer make a 32-bit version.  So... I need to get 64-bit working.

When I create the connection in the 64-bit version of DBeaver, pointing to the 64-bit ODBC connection I created and tested earlier, I get the following error:

`[PSQL][ODBC Client Interface]Parameter number out of range.`

I have no idea how to make this connection work. Either there's a bug in 64-bit DBeaver or I'm doing something wrong.  It's *not* an architecture mismatch, as best I can tell.  When I create the 64-bit source in Windows, the Test connection is successful.  But 64-bit DBeaver refuses to connect to that 64-bit ODBC source.

**UPDATE:**
@mirthiel 's answer is correct, except you have to add *three* driver files: `pvjdbc2.jar`, `pvjdbc2x.jar`, and `jpscs.jar`

Comment: Does the error during connection or does it occur running a query?  What version of PSQL are you using?  I'm using PSQL v11.30 and was able to create a connection within DBeaver pointing to a 64 bit DSN pointing to Demodata.  Does that work?  Have you tried the JDBC driver connection to Pervasive?

Comment: I don't know how to try the JDBC connection. DBeaver doesn't have a "JDBC" option, except to the point that a bunch of them (including ODBC) appear to use JDBC under the hood

Comment: Does the error during connection or does it occur running a query?

Comment: It happens when creating a connection when I test the connection, and when I try to use the connection in any way. I don’t get as far as a list of tables; there is no connection at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DBeaver is a Java based program and can use JDBC, you might try using the Pervasive JDBC driver.  To do this, add a new Driver in the Driver Manager.  In the `Class Name` use:

```
com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver
```

For the `URL Template`, I used:

```
jdbc:pervasive://servername.1583/dbname?transport=tcp
```

I then added the Pervasive JDBC Library (by clicking `Add File` in the `Libraries` tab.  I selected the Pervasive driver (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\pvjdbc2.jar` in my PSQL install).

Once the Driver is setup, adding a Connection using the Driver should work and you should be able to use the Connection.

Comment: I’ll try this. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Tried it. First off, on my computer the path is "Actian" not "Pervasive Software".  Also set "no authentication".  Test Connection gives this error: `Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to database | com/pervasive/pscs/Manager`

Comment: Got it!  The kicker was this: "The connection works if you add the two other jar files from the Pervasive driver bin folder, the `jpscs.jar` and the `pvjdbc2x.jar`." Found here: https://coderanch.com/t/303696/databases/Connection-PervasiveSQL-fails